# I can't get information from the database (firebase) in expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want get info firebase in expo, but i can't, I get this error

> ERROR: child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "user/Carregando...". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

i too tried using try and catch too, but it basically doesn't change anything, I don't know if the error is in the code or in the expo

> ERROR WITH TRY/CATCH: error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\bellu\OneDrive\Desktop\Development\study\studydb\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "from" (10:0)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { db } from './src/database';
import { onValue, ref } from 'firebase/database';


export default function App() {

  const [nome, setNome] = useState('Carregando...');

  useEffect(() => {
    
    function readData(){
      const start = ref(db, 'user/' + nome);
      onValue(start, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        setNome(data.nome)
      })
    }
    try {
      readData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, [])


  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,

      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
      <Text>{nome}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried get info in database, but what I try doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

A path in the Firebase Realtime Database can not contain any `.` characters, so the default value that you specify for `nome` here is not valid:

```
const [nome, setNome] = useState('Carregando...');
```

Either specify the name of a user that actually exists, or use a different way to detect that the data is still loading, like:

```
const [nome, setNome] = useState();
...
  <Text>{nome ? nome : 'Carregando...'}</Text>
```